# Why the second half of list is note operated on in a recursive call in merge sort

Tags: python, mergesort

I am given a task to implement merge sort in python. I have written the code but I am stuck at Why the code doesn't print part_b of the list after a recursive call and how shall I fix it.

Below is the code

```
def merge_sort(list_sort):
    """splits the list in two parts until each part is left with one member"""

    if len(list_sort) ==  1:
        print len(list_sort)
        return list_sort

    if len(list_sort)>= 2:
        x= len(list_sort) / 2
        part_a = list_sort[:x]
        part_b = list_sort[x:]
        print part_a , part_b
        merge_sort(part_a)
        merge_sort(part_b)

    return merge(part_a, part_b)


def merge(left , right):
    """merges the two parts of list after sorting them"""
    print left, right 
    sorted_list = []
    if len(left) >= len(right):
        i = len(left)
        while i != 0:
            if left[i] > right[i]:
                sorted_list.append(right[i])
            else :
                sorted_list.append(left[i])
            i = i-1
        sorted_list += right[i:]
    else :
        i = len(right)
        while i != 0:
            if left[i] > right[i]:
                sorted_list.append(right[i])
            else :
                sorted_list.append(left[i])
            i = i-1
        sorted_list += left[i:]
    return sorted_list

details = [3, 7, 5, 12, 14, 11, 2, 6]
print merge_sort(details)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your claim is incorrect.  I updated your `print`s to label the output

```
    print "SORT A", part_a , "\tB", part_b

print "MERGE left", left, "\tright", right
```

and got the expected trace, until it crashed on the index mishandling in the merge phase.  As others have noted, this is from failing to save the return value from `merge`.

```
SORT A [3, 7, 5, 12]    B [14, 11, 2, 6]
SORT A [3, 7]   B [5, 12]
SORT A [3]  B [7]
1
1
MERGE left [3]  right [7]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 44, in <module>
    print merge_sort(details)
  File "so.py", line 13, in merge_sort
    merge_sort(part_a)
  File "so.py", line 13, in merge_sort
    merge_sort(part_a)
  File "so.py", line 16, in merge_sort
    return merge(part_a, part_b)
  File "so.py", line 26, in merge
    if left[i] > right[i]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**UPDATE per OP COMMENT**

Part B isn't operated on because of your (valid) call order: the algorithm must finish sorting and merging part A before it works on part B.  You don't get that far because of the index range error.  You faulted on trying to merge [3] and [7] -- parts AAA and AAB, respectively.  You never made it back up the stack (AA and AB) to work on the original part B.

Comment: I am asking about why the part B i.e [14,11,2.6] is not operated on in the recursive call

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use your merge_sort as if it operates in place, but it does not. You need to capture its return value:

```
part_a = merge_sort(part_a)
part_b = merge_sort(part_b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `merge_sort` function returns the sorted list but at both locations you call it you discard the result. You need to assign the result (bind it to a name) so that you can pass those results to `merge`:

```
if len(list_sort) >= 2:
    x= len(list_sort) / 2
    part_a = list_sort[:x]
    part_b = list_sort[x:]
    print part_a , part_b
    sorted_part_a = merge_sort(part_a)
    sorted_part_b = merge_sort(part_b)
    return merge(sorted_part_a, sorted_part_b)
```